# Sentient Bomb in a city on the moon?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, weapon, sentience

I would like to know the title of the short story that I believe takes place on the moon.  The setting is a mall or some other very public location and the main character is a police officer.  She needs to talk a sentient bomb out of exploding.  I know there was the John Carpenter film "Dark Star" with a similar plot line but I'm trying to identify the short story and the author.

Comment: A nitpick:  The sentience was a human mind that was built into the bomb, the bomb was a perfectly ordinary uranium gun design otherwise.  It was just a future-tech version of a suicide bomber, I wouldn't really call the bomb sentient.

Comment: There's also a Philip K. Dick story with a similar plot (not happening on the moon or near a mall). And then there's *[The Centauri Device](http://www.zone-sf.com/wordworks/centdmjh.html)*.

Comment: @Loren - now that I've reread the story-it's probably been 15-20 years-I see that you are correct.

Comment: @Gilles - I'd love to know the name of the PKD story if you can recall.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[John Varley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Varley_%28author%29)'s short story *Bagatelle* has this plot.

Original publication appears to have been 1976. My copy is in the 1980 anthology *The Barbie Murders* (named after a short story in the volume, for anyone who's starting to get confused).

It opens

> There was a bomb on the Leystrasse, level forty-five, right outside the Bagatelle Flower and Gift Shoppe, about a hundred meters down the promenade from the Prosperity Plaza.
>
> "I am a bomb," the bomb said to passersby. ...

Comment: **Aside:** I've often felt that Varley is particularly good at setting the hook in a few words. The opening to *Steel Beach* is a classic that way, and this story is a fine example as well.

Comment: That is absolutely it. Thanks!  Available online at http://web.archive.org/web/20070212114356/www.scifi.com/scifiction/classics/classics_archive/varley/index.html

Comment: @stangeland +1 for link, will give it a read :)