# Nuclear explosion in lunar city

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, moon, nuclear-weapons

I utterly forget the plot of this tale, but it includes a vivid description of a nuclear bomb going off deep inside a large, underground lunar city of many levels. The explosion, set off in secret, is deep enough that it does not emerge onto the surface immediately. The death toll is catastrophic.

The story may date to the 80s. In an English-language collection of short stories.

Comment: There is a scene in Varley's short story "Bagatelle" in which a character visualizes the effects of nuclear detonation in a lunar city. I ID'ed it for [a slightly different questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/sentient-bomb-in-a-city-on-the-moon), and quoted the memorable opening line.

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely the story I was searching for. The story is online at:
http://web.archive.org/web/20070212114356/www.scifi.com/scifiction/classics/classics_archive/varley/index.html